# Expecting the Unexpected in Expect

Tags: expect

How can I give an instruction to expect, when it sees anything other than what it expects?

Example, I attempt to automate a login.  For anything other than a successful attempt, I need the script to mail me an error.  How do I expect unexpected output?  (I know some outcomes, like connection denied, or wrong password, but I want to catch everything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
set timeout 10; # set a reasonable timeout

# expect and send username/password ...

set success 0
set err_msg ""
expect {
  "Login success!" {
    set success 1
  }
  eof {
    set err_msg $expect_out(buffer)
  }
  timeout {
    expect *
    set err_msg $expect_out(buffer)
  }
}

if {! $success} {
  send_mail $err_msg
  exit 1
}
```