# Use things like else in expect block of expect script

Tags: expect

In expect block  of expect script like as below:

```
expect {  
    "matched_string" {puts "string is matched"}  
    "I want to get strings else" {puts "string is unmatched"}  #(1)  
}
```

At the (1), I want to get all strings which difference with "matched_string". It is same as "else".I can solve with the default or timeout but I don't want to wait.

How can I do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Show some of the incoming text, and show your desired output.

Comment: The content of example.txt has one line only but  is unpredictable.  
cat example.txt --> matched_string  

And it will print "string is matched"  

When I cat example.txt with content is difference matched_string, I want to print "string is unmatched"

Comment: take a look at this: [Expecting the Unexpected in Expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132153/)